# Large excel(poi) report- HEAP memory issue

Tags: apache-poi, heap-memory

How to solve the Heap memory issue when downloading a large excel(poi) report

Comment: Do you really expect an answer to this question except of: Provide more memory? This question is similar to: How to solve the typo issue when writing program code? Answer: Train up typing.

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380765/read-huge-excel-file500k-rows-in-java ? as an addition to that, I have a fork of excel-streaming-reader which is more up to date than the one mentioned in that page (cf https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader)