# Apache poi application is in stuck while reading file with 500k lines

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use the following code to read really large excel files - up to 500k lines with up to 100 columns

```
public List<ExcelLine> getExcelLines(Path path, int batchSize) {

    log.info("Reading excel file");

    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(path.toFile())) {
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      ...
    }
}
```

The idea was to read by batches to avoid OutOfMemory error and it works for small files. However, once I call the method with large file, I see `log.info` statement, but then the application is in stuck. So a breakpoint inside the try-with-resources statement is not reachable.

Does anybody have ideas what to do in such case?

Comment: Related: [Read Huge Excel file(500K rows) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42380765/12567365)

Comment: [More suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+poi+read+large+excel+files+site:stackoverflow.com). Maybe some of these approaches will work for you.

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75860852/230513).

Answer (score 1):

The most popular [suggestion](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) didn't work for me because it hasn't been updated for 2 years and has conflicts with the latest Apache POI implementation. I found another repo, that is essentially a fork of the original one but has updates: https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader. This is the code that works for me:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(file.getFileLocation());
     Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder().setAvoidTempFiles(false).bufferSize(4096).open(inputStream)) {
...
}
```